# How to get on screen text inside UILabel if text does not fit frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, cgrect

```
UILabel * yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame....];
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
yourLabel.text = @"Some long text that not fit frame, many words, many symbols";
```

On screen i see "Some long text that not..."
How to get string *"Some long text that not"* or tail *"fit frame, many words, many symbols"*?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: i do not need to change font size. I need to get NSString * fetText = @"Some long text that not"; and NSString * tailText = @"fit frame, many words, many symbols";

Answer (score 0):

Please one line add your code and check it

```
[yourLabel sizeToFit];
```